# How to fix Boot-Repair aborted message when converting to separate efi from bios mode?

Tags: uefi

I have installed Ubuntu on pre-installed Windows 8 laptop. I installed Ubuntu in bios mode. As Windows 8 is in efi mode I have to convert Ubuntu also in efi mode.

To do this I downloaded Boot-Repair and made my USB bootable. When I go to Boot-Repair after selecting the option separate efi partition and clicking on apply it gives me message **aborted**.

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Answer (score 1):

Was the error message simply "aborted?" If so, that's unusually terse and uninformative. If the tool gave a longer error message, it's important that you report the *entire* message if you expect to get help.

That said, you may want to consult [my Web page on EFI boot loaders for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) Installing any of them should get your system booting in EFI mode. You can test [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) without installing it; just download the USB flash drive or CD-R image and prepare a suitable medium. If you installed Ubuntu *without* a separate `/boot` partition, rEFInd will probably boot your computer in EFI mode without any additional configuration.